# Why can't I restart my bounty question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, unanswered-questions

I have a question that has not correct answer. I have started bounty for it. Some guy gave incorrect answer on it. I would like to re-submit bounty but cannot see the way.

EDITED:

Here it is:
   [Struts 2 discard cache header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841925/struts-2-discard-cache-header)

Comment: Can you give a link to the question?

Comment: It [appears](http://stackoverflow.com/users/149818?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) the OP only has [one bounty question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745512) on SO (but he also [lost 100 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841925) that I can't explain). @que

Comment: @The Cat Cheers for the links. I think the latter is a bounty that expired.

Comment: @Questions - just edited to show the link

Comment: Without the "why?", I guess this is a duplicate of [Can i start a new bounty to a bounty expired question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40414/can-i-start-a-new-bounty-to-a-bounty-expired-question) (which was closed in favor of [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

This is effectively completed, because

- bounty system is no longer tied to accepting an answer in any way
- you can issue multiple bounties on your question if necessary

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done, such are [the rules of the bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work): You need to be extremely careful which answer you accept, because the decision can't be changed.

In your case, if I caught the right question, it was indeed a case of no valid answers being there, and the bounty auto-expiring. That is indeed tough luck, but the question can never be accepted nor the bounty restarted, that is the way it (sadly) currently  is.

You could try editing your question [to push it back to the top](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions), and point out that the answer is not correct; alternatively, you can try starting a new question - if possible, modifying it or stressing another aspect of it so it constitutes a new question, so it doesn't get closed as a duplicate.

There are several suggestions to change this systems but I don't think it's very far up on the priorities lists.

Comment: but I have not committed that question as correct! Even more, I've decreased it.

Comment: @Dewfy yup, the bounty auto-expired. You should have got plenty of notifications about that (even through E-Mail).

Comment: during this period I have not got an answer, that is why I want to leverage bounty again. Yes, it was expired, but how can I confirm absolutely wrong answer? May be better rephrase: what should I do to get an answer in this circumstance?

Comment: @Dewfy: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions